# Definition of "swelled class" - how can a "subclass" be an "element" of a class unless it is a "set"?

Tags: set-theory

Context: clarification of my understanding as a self-learner.

Reference: Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (rev. ed, 2010), chapter $2$: Some Basics of Class-Set Theory:  $\S 2$: Transitivity and supercompleteness.

Definition $2.2$ says:

> We will say that a class $A$ is *swelled* if $A$ contains with every element $y$ all *subclasses* $x$ of $y$ as well -- in other words, every subclass of every element of $A$ is an element of $A$. Thus $A$ is swelled iff the following condition holds: $$(\forall x) (\forall y) [(x \subseteq y \land y \in A) \implies x \in A]$$

My question is: why would one discuss *subclasses* of $x$ being *elements* of $A$? I have two problems with this:

- a) A subclass of a set is a subset
- b) An element of a class is a set.

Now I'm not sure exactly what model of class theory is needed to demonstrate the first one -- I believe it needs Axiom of Specification and Axiom of Powers, but my deeper understanding of this is lacking; I'm just following other wisdom.

However, b) seems to me quite fundamental, as (in my understanding) the only things allowed to be *elements* of classes are *sets* (or perhaps things that are neither sets nor classes, I'm not certain about that). In other words, *classes* are not allowed to have *proper classes* (that is, classes that are specifically *not sets*) as elements. (Or maybe the term "member" needs to be used, to distinguish it from elementhood of a set.)

Perhaps the *true* question here is: are there models of class-set theory which *do* allow proper classes to be elements of classes, and the restriction disallowing this to happen is nothing more than a (possibly unspoken) consequence of whatever axiom schema has been imposed upon our initial, general, completely vanilla concept of a "class"?

If there *are* such models (allowing proper classes to be elements of classes), what exactly is the model called which *does* so restrict elementhood of classes?